# CiviCase: Activities duplicated when filed

Tags: civicase, activities

Recently, when filing an Activity to a Case file, the Activity is being duplicated; one copy is filed as expected, the other is not filed and a prefix "Filed on Case XXX" is added to the Subject field.

Case-filed Activities are configured to be visible in general Activity views.

This change in behaviour occurred about two months ago, I think.

Is this expected behaviour, and merely a configuration issue I have missed? Or is it a bug?

Running CiviCRM / CiviCase version 5.65.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's expected. See lab ticket https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4220 and PR https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/26091

Comment: Thank you, very helpful to be pointed to that history. We are left with the oddity of having to update the status of two versions of the same activity in our workflow, to avoid confusion! Having the "move to / copy to case" options would make a lot of sense.   But I can see I'm not the only one to find the current fudge to be unsatisfactory.